# Intellij 11.0.1 seems to be ignoring my .hgignore file

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea, tortoisehg, hgignore

I have the following .hgignore file that should keep Intellij's constantly changing internal config files from polluting our source control.

```
syntax: glob
.idea/*
target/*
logs/*
out/*
myapp.iml
myapp-web.iml
```

Tortoise and the command line seem to respect the fact that files like ".idea/dataSources.xml" are not meant to be added to source control but intellij's hg4idea are constantly asking if I would like to add files like ".idea/dataSources.xml" to source control.

Is my .hgignore file just wrong or is there a bug in Intellij?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-65229), please vote. As a workaround you can [ignore files](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-ignored-files.html) in `Settings` | `Version Control` | `Ignored Files`.

Answer (score 1):

To add files to the IntelliJ ignore list go to:

- Settings
- Version Control
- Ignored Files

[image: Settings]